# ImageDataBunch function is not defined-FastAI windows

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, computer-vision, fast-ai

I am trying to install fastai in my windows 10.

My laptop has no GPU, I am using pip in cmd to install fastai.

In [pip page](https://pypi.org/project/fastai/), they mentioned to install pytroch before installing fastai.

I followed that step,

For [pytorch](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)-

```
pip install torch==1.6.0+cpu torchvision==0.7.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Then, For fastai-

```
pip install fastai
```

These python packages are installed successfully.

```
from fastai.vision import *
```

This statement is imported fastai.vision successfully,

But when I use the ImageDataBunch function,

```
data = ImageDataBunch.from_folder(path, train=".", valid_pct=0.2, size=512, bs=4, seed=24)
```

It shows error, `NameError: name 'ImageDataBunch' is not defined`

I do not know what is happening, Could you please help me to solve this error, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from fastai.vision.data import ImageDataLoaders
```

Instead of using `ImageDataBunch` use `data = ImageDataLoaders.from_folder(path, valid_pct=0.2)`  check here for more [fastai vision documentation](https://docs.fast.ai/vision.data)

Comment: I get the following error : 

    type object 'Image' has no attribute 'size'

Comment: try with upgrading your PIL version and then restart your instance

Comment: I get NameError: name 'ImageDataBunch' is not defined in Colab. Any suggestion? I did import it like this. from fastai.vision import *

Comment: "check here for more fastai vision documentation",  Link is not working as of today.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when forgetting to use `from fastbook import *`

Answer (score 0):

Just install "!pip install fastai==1.0.58" instead of "!pip install fastai" and you are good to go

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).